# BLE Beacon connection to Peripheral device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I have one device which works as beacon and another device(D2) which works in peripheral mode and communicate to smart phone as in connection mode.

Now I want to send my data from beacon to D2 which is in peripheral mode.

So is it possible to communicate between beacon and D2.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. A beacon is considered to be a peripheral device, and only a central device can scan/connect and read data from a peripheral device. As such, you cannot communicate between the beacon and D2 unless the D2 has central capabilities.

You can find more information here:-

- [BLE beacon technology made simple](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2018/08/ble-made-simple-a-complete-guide-to-ble-bluetooth-beacons/)
- [Getting started with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer)